# Is it necessary to have a hosted website to use facebook api, to authenticate users using facebook

Tags: localhost, facebook-graph-api

I want to use facebook graph api to authenticate users on my webapp which is on my localhost. But as I see it when I tried to get access key facebook is asking for website url.
Is it that I should have public url of my site to use facebook graph api?? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can authorize even for localhost as http://localhost/ is a valid url, you just need to fill in to site url in the developers application.

You can then redirect to this URL after login.

(Ii the case that you run you web app on your localhost but actual users get to it via LAN you need to fill your LAN IP - for example http://192.168.0.2/)

To put it in other words - you need to fill url to which redirect after web app authorization as site URL on WEB-SITE tab of the setting in Developers application. You can pu there any valid URL (of directory I think) - even if it's not accesible from any other computer then yours.